# ckanapi create line break using markdown

Tags: api, markdown, ckan

I'm creating the description of a number of resources using the python ckanapi. I'd like to create line breaks, which is easy if using the UI (two spaces followed by return key) but I can't figure out how to do it over the api.

Is there a way to start text on a new line using markdown?

Comment: What code are you currently using to call the API? Have you tried using two spaces: `"line one  \nline two"`?

Comment: I'm just filling in a resource description. I get the same result whether I use the ckanapi (resouce_update) or filling out the description via the UI.  Yes, \n didn't work. I just want "Some text on the first line. <line break> Some text on the next line."

Comment: Keep in mind, that with markdown a single line break (`\n`) does nothing, it's only for better readability. If you want to start a new paragraph, use two line breaks (`\n\n`)

Comment: When I add \n to the text, \n shows up in text rather than produce a new line. There must be a way to do this..

Answer (score 0):

line break in markdown:

```
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well. For me, two spaces followed by `\n` worked.

So: `First line  \nSecond line`